# Check if Rails Database Query Returns Nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to know if a Rails database query returns a row or not (I don't need to know whats in the row, just if a row is returned).

I can do this:

```
academic_year = AcademicYear.find_by_raw_input(year)

if academic_year 
 ...
end
```

but if I mistype and do a `find_all_by`:

```
academic_year = AcademicYear.find_all_by_raw_input(year)
```

then an empty array is returned, which causes the `if` statement to be true.

I know, I should be careful and just avoid the `all` call, but is there a rails-esque call to see if the return result from any query (`all` or not) is `nil`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `find_by_...` will return `nil`, and `find_all_by_...` will return `[]`. I think what you're looking for is [`.blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F).

```
if !academic_year.blank?
  #...
end
```

In console

```
> AcademicYear.find_by_raw_input(some_non_existent_year).blank?
  => true
> AcademicYear.find_all_by_raw_input(some_non_existent_year).blank?
  => true
```

Comment: Ruby on Rails extends `Object` to include some helper methods. Among them is `present?()` which returns exactly `!blank?`. `if x.present?` may be easier to read than `if !x.blank?`. [See Ruby on Rails docs for `Object`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)